# SEO Suggestion For My Blog

Tags: seo, wordpress

I have a programming tutorial blog, which has decent traffic. However, I am interested to do some basic SEO for my blog to get it optimized. I want to do it myself by learning. I was wondering if experts here can suggest how I should proceed please?

Also, if you please review my blog and suggest the most common SEO concern that come to your mind first, those will be helpful as well. My blog site url is as follow:

http://codesamplez.com/

Looking forward to your feedback soon.

Answer (score 1):

Good to see that it is a WordPress blog, here are some quick tips that should get you started on the right track -

1. Install WordPress SEO by Yoast plug-in, it will do wonders for you! Some of the cool things that this plug-in does is it provides you with easy onpage optimization tips for your target keyword on your target page
2. Install Google Analytics by Yoast plug-in! I know you can simply stick the GA Code in your theme directly, however do the tweaks that Joost de Valk (Yoast) suggests in this post and then you can use [this custom GA Dashboard](http://yoast.com/google-analytics-dashboard/) (custom reporting FTW!!)
3. Use the sitemaps generated by the WordPress SEO plug-in that I mentioned and stick that in your Google Webmasters account, ditto for Bing WMT
4. In case if you are using rich media in your posts (images and videos), then install the following plug-ins Google XML Sitemap for Images, Google XML Sitemap for Videos (both of them are by Amit Agarwal). They will generate separate image sitemaps and video sitemaps.

Hope this helps!